# Exp-resso Store not registering Shipping Country

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce

I've just added a new country to my client's webshop (Belgium), and I've added a rule to their Shipping method which checks for this country, and then sets a shipping-rate. Belgium shows up in the dropdown on our checkout-process now, but when I select it, and go to the next step (order confirmation before payment) it'll show our other country (The Netherlands) instead... so apparently selection isn't coming through, even though the dropdown renders fine and the value is set properly... Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah, nevermind, fieldnames weren't set properly. Sorry!